# How to build a vite project with homepage set to "./"? (More details given below)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, production

Making a react project created using vite...
I want to build the project such that in the build folder, I get an HTML file that I can directly open in the browser without using npm build command or anything like that.

If I had used create-react-app, I could've set `homepage:'./'` in the package.json file to achieve the same.

How do I get the same in vite react project?

My vite.config.js file (if that matters):

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    base: "./",
});
```

I've tried setting the `base` to  `./` but it didn't work. When I open the index.html file the console only has one message:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/taran/vs-workspace/My%20creations/attendance/projecting/homepage/dist/assets/index-a4a61d14.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).`

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Turn off the CORS mode inside of Google Chrome